# How to get partial result from doctrine query builder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have a product entity in which it has an array as attributes:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ProductPicture", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    protected $pictures;

    /** 
    * @Accessor(getter="getCover") 
    */
    private $cover;
    public function getCover()
    {
        if($this->pictures->count() > 0) {
            return $this->pictures[0];
        }
        return new ProductPicture();
    }
```

Now in my query builder, I have the following code:

```
 $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p')
            ->from("SiteMainBundle:Product", 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
            ;
```

The issue here is that I don't want to be selecting all of p's attribute. So I only wanted to get the first ProductPicture in the pictures array (in my case above it's similar to the getCover() method). How do I do this?

So far I can filter out the the partial attributes that I want by doing:

```
 $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p.name, p.id')
                ->from("SiteMainBundle:Product", 'p')
                ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c')
                ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
                ->innerJoin('p.pictures', 'pictures')
                ;
```

so in the example above I have done inner joined on the pictures, but how do I get the first element from here?

In conclusion, my question is how do I select/query the first ProductPicture in the pictures array using the query builder? Because when I do:

$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p')

it returns the whole product attributes, but I don't want the whole product attributes.. I only wanted some of them, such as the id, name, etc. However one of the product attributes is actually an entity (which is the ProductPicture), so how do I return this in the select statement?

**EDIT:**

Here's a SQL equivalent on how the pictures should be inner joined:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `product` 
JOIN  `product_picture` ON  `product`.id =  `product_picture`.product_id
WHERE  `product`.id =100
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You mean where to put the `where` or how to execute the query?

Comment: I am asking is there a way to convert the SQL into a query builder? I am a bit confused of translating the limit into the query. I know there's a setMaxResults in doctrine, but that gives a different result.

Comment: What kind of different result? like a different picture? or the whole row is different?

Comment: I upvoted your question because it's an interesting one, but it is also ambiguous based on your attempted query builder and the SQL provided afterwards. If you could provide us with an example of what data you would like returned, as if the query was successfully executed, then I can help figure out how to build the query.

Comment: @Adam-E I edited/updated the question again

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady added more details in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, if it's a one to many, the normal mySQL behaviour is returning several records with redundant product data, if the same case happens here, then only returning the first record should do the trick.
***PS***: *assuming the ProductPicture entity has a url property that you want to get*

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p.id, p.name, pictures.url')
            ->from("SiteMainBundle:Product", 'p')
            ->innerJoin('p.category', 'c')
            ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
            ->innerJoin('p.pictures', 'pictures')
            ;
```

Comment: Okay so the issue with this query is that it returns the same product id couple times. I'll add more details in the original question.

Comment: you need to understand mysql first, if we have product p, with images img1, img2, img3, and you do the query, it would return 3 records, all 3 records have same product p, but each record has a different image, (p, img1), (p, img2), (p, img3), you should specify which image you want exactly, like image with main=1 for example or something like that

Comment: I understand all that, I think the solution is to do group by

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom repository method with the DQL for your entity, then call it from the controller

You can name the repository method whatever you want, for this example I'm using `findProductWithPicture`

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param integer $id
     */
    public function findProductWithPicture($id)
    {
        $dql = <<<SQL
SELECT
    p.id    id,
    p.name  name,
    q       picture
FROM
    Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\ProductPicture q,
    Shopious\MainBundle\Entity\Product p
WHERE
    p.id        = :picture_id  AND
    q.product   = p.id
SQL;

        $query = $this->_em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('picture_id', $id);

        return $query->setMaxResults(1)->getResult();
    }
}
```

To use this from the controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$product = $em->getRepository('ShopiousMainBundle:Product')->findProductWithPicture($id);

return $this->render('ShopiousMainBundle:Product:show.html.twig', array(
    'product' => $product[0]
));
```

In the rendered Twig template, you can access them like so

```
<p>{{ product.id }}
<p>{{ product.name }}
<p>{{ product.picture.whatever_property }}
```